# Simple call string solution XNA?

Tags: c#, string, xna

In Draw, I successfully drawn my string where I want it. The problem is I want it to be more efficient.

Code:

```c#
spriteBatch.DrawString (font, "Are you sure you wish to quit?", new Vector2 (...),  Color.White);
```

In `Vector2` I call `MeasureString`, and had to rewrite the string... And it's ugly...

I've tried 3 different ways of saying : `string sureQuit = "Are you sure..."` : and calling `(font, sureQuit, ...)`.
And I'm constantly receiving errors. I know there is an extremely simple way to create a string and call it,but I cannot find any resource of such a simple thing.

I figured it out... My class was inherited from an abstract class, which inherited from DrawableGameComponent. Therefore in my public struct I had to call:
`this.sureQuit = "Are you sure you wish to quit?"`

Comment: Is this an XNA Framework project?

Comment: "I'm constantly receiving errors" What are the errors exactly?

Comment: I just recently figured it out, and would like to answer my own question,  but it won't let me answer until 8hrs pass. The errors were it was set to null, and asked for a new reference.  Then a get set was required. But like I said, I got it. Thanks for your interest in helping though, it is much appreciated